# html dropdown with paginate and search

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, pagination, bootstrap-5

I'm new to web applications in general, and I'm starting with Rails. I'm trying to create a 'dropdown' menu in the *html.erb* file using the 'form.collection_select' command, but I'd like it to include **Paginate** and **Search Item**. The biggest issue is pagination; I spent several days searching in the internet but was unable to find any solution. I could add pagination like this

[image]

, but it isn't what should be. How do I make a dropdown menu using **paginate** that is inside the *dropdown-menu*? javascript? css?